# Unable to build a calculated datasource from a user list request to AdminDirectory

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-app-maker

I have been trying to work on a requirement where I made an app using App Maker, it is a directory app, user will open the homepage for that app and should be able to see the list of his contacts in the same OrgUnit that he is in on G Suite.

I understand that the default people or directory model does not show the orgUnitPath attribute, so I used the AdminDirectory directly.

In application settings I enabled the AdminDirectory API.
I created a new calculated datasource named Test.
Then I added 3 fields to the datasource: primaryEmail, fllName, and orgUnitPath.
Then in the events I added the following script:

```
var usersArr = [];
var pageToken, page;
var conditions = {
    customer: 'my_customer',
    query: 'orgUnitPath=\'/OU_NAME\'',
    pageToken: pageToken 
}

do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list(conditions);

    for (var i=0;i<page.users.length;i++)
    {
        console.log(page.users[i].orgUnitPath);
        usersArr.push(page.users[i].primaryEmail,page.users[i].name.fullName,page.users[i].orgUnitPath);

    }

    //page.users.forEach(function(user) {
        //usersArr.push(user.primaryEmail, user.name.fullName, user.orgUnitPath);
    //});

    if (page.nextPageToken) {
        conditions.pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
    }
} while (page.pageToken);

console.log(usersArr.length);
console.log(usersArr);
return usersArr;
```

[image: Query event for the datasource]

When I try to preview the app, I get the following error in console:

> E - Tue Oct 16 11:36:43 GMT+300 2018 - The function queryRecords must
>   return an array of records, but the array contained an element that
>   was not a record. Error: The function queryRecords must return an
>   array of records, but the array contained an element that was not a
>   record.
>
> E - Tue Oct 16 11:36:43 GMT+300 2018 - Executing query for datasource
>   Test: (Error) : The function queryRecords must return an array of
>   records, but the array contained an element that was not a record.
>
> E - Tue Oct 16 11:36:43 GMT+300 2018 - Executing query for datasource
>   Test failed.

I think I am not getting the point where I need to make the returned array into proper format to be accepted by the datasource so I can use it with it.

Not sure if I did put all the required details.. Please let me know of any missing information and I'll put them here!

I would really appreciate any help or guidance on this...

Regards

Comment: In which event did you add this script? From what I recall, calculated models/datasources only have an onAfterLoad event, which would not be the correct place for this script. Generally when setting up calculated datasources I put my script in a function inside a server script and then in the datasource server script I call return MyFunction();

Comment: I added that in the Query event inside the data source settings... I updated the question with the screenshot for the script..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Maker is expecting you to return an array of [Record](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#Record) objects for the datasource you are defining (in this case "Test" records).

You can put this script in the datasource server script or as a function that's called from the datasource server script as Markus suggested.

```
var usersArr = [];
var pageToken, page;
var conditions = {
    customer: 'my_customer',
    query: 'orgUnitPath=\'/OU_NAME\'',
    pageToken: pageToken 
}

do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list(conditions);

    for (var i = 0; i < page.users.length; i++) {
        var userRecord = app.models.Test.newRecord();

        userRecord.primaryEmail = page.users[i].primaryEmail;
        userRecord.fullName = page.users[i].name.fullName;
        userRecord.orgUnitPath = page.users[i].orgUnitPath;

        usersArr.push(userRecord);
    }

    if (page.nextPageToken) {
        conditions.pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
    }
} while (page.pageToken);

return usersArr;
```

Comment: Ok so it was in the type of returned object.. Thanks a lot for the edits on the code!